# Wrong decode result in python

Tags: python

Can't figure out by debugging, why I got `b` in front of my hidden string?

I get this string in my result:
 `'1101000011001010110110001101100011'`

```
def retr(filename):
    img = Image.open(filename)
    binary = ''

    if img.mode in ('RGBA'):
        img = img.convert('RGBA')
        datas = img.getdata()

        for item in datas:
            digit = decode(rgb2hex(item[0], item[1], item[2]))
            if digit == None:
                pass
            else:
                binary = binary + digit
                if (binary[-16:] == '1111111111111110'):
                   # print("Success")
                    return bin2str(binary[:-16])

        return str(bin2str(binary))
    return "Incorrect Image Mode, Couldn't Retrieve"
```

But result in console is: `b'hello'`. Where is `b` from?

Doing some pre fucntion before `retr()`:

```
def rgb2hex(r, g, b):
    return '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(r, g, b)


def hex2rgb(hexcode):
     return int(hexcode[1:3], 16), int(hexcode[3:5], 16), int(hexcode[5:7], 16)


def str2bin(message):
    binary = bin(int(binascii.hexlify(message.encode("ascii")), 16))
    return binary[2:]


def bin2str(binary):
    message = binascii.unhexlify('%x' % (int('0b' + binary, 2)))
    return message
```

help ,please, to catch that `b`..

Comment: a `b` prefix indicates that you have a bytestring, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes

Comment: @cssko              and can't I remove this?

Comment: Why do you want to "remove" it?

Comment: @x24 you can decode it, see my answer

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  I meant, just see my string without 'b'.

Comment: Try `print(my_string)` and you won't see the `b` anymore. It isn't *part of the bytestring*, it's just how it is being represented.

Comment: The b isn't part of the bytestring. It's just in the console to let you know it's a bytestring and not a regular string.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga couldn't get the rigtht result under your example. See the answer, it helped me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bin2str` is returning a byte literal. You can use `.decode()` to return a string instead.

```
def bin2str(binary):
    message = binascii.unhexlify('%x' % (int('0b' + binary, 2)))
    return message.decode("utf-8") # or encoding of choice
```

Comment: Yea, it helped me, thank you a lot for this! Now I've figure out, how I should use it. Thanks one more time.

Answer (score 3):

```
x = b'hello'
print(x)
   b'hello'
print(x.decode('utf-8'))
   'hello'
```

I hope this shows enough so that you understand how to get it back to a utf-8 string

Answer (score 1):

I believe that any byte string will include: "b'" before the string to indicate it came from a binary value. After you convert the binary value to the string, you can do a replace function:

```
newstring = message.replace("b", "")
newstring = message.replace("'", "")
```